# Rails - Eager Load Association on an Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, eager-loading

**EDIT - Using 'includes' generates a SQL 'IN' clause.  When using Oracle this has a 1,000 item limit.  It will not work for my company.  Are there any other solutions out there?**

Is it possible to eager load an association on an association?

For example, let's say I have an Academy class, and an academy has many students.  Each student belongs_to student_level

```
class Academy < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :academy
  belongs_to :student_level
end

class StudentLevel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
end
```

Is it possible to tailor the association in Academy so that when I load the students, I ALWAYS load the student_level with the student?

In other words, I would like the following section of code to produce one or two queries total, not one query for every student:

```
@academy.students.each do |student|
  puts "#{student.name} - #{student.student_level.level_name}"
end
```

I know I can do this if I change students from an association to a method, but I don't want to do that as I won't be able to reference students as an association in my other queries.  I also know that I can do this in SQL in the following manner, but I want to know if there's a way to do this without finder_sql on my association, because now I need to update my finder_sql anytime my default scope changes, and this won't preload the association:

```
SELECT students.*, student_levels.* FROM students
LEFT JOIN student_levels ON students.student_level_id = student_levels.id
WHERE students.academy_id = ACADEMY_ID_HERE
```

Comment: Old question, but regarding the IN-clause generated by `.includes()` mentioned in the edit: The class method `.eager_load()` can be used to generate a left outer join instead of an in-clause: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/eager_load

Comment: Thanks for the update

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using `includes` to eager load the data?

```
class Academy < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students

  # you can probably come up with better method name
  def students_with_levels
    # not sure if includes works off associations, see alternate below if it does not
    self.students.includes(:student_level)
  end

  def alternate
    Student.where("academy_id = ?", self.id).includes(:student_level)
  end
end
```

see also: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

should result in 3 queries

- the initial find on Academy
- the query for a collection of Student objects
- the query for all of those Students StudentLevel objects

**Additions:**

```
# the same can be done outside of methods
@academy.students.includes(:student_level).each do |student|
  puts "#{student.name} - #{student.student_level.level_name}"
end

Student.where("academy_id = ?", @academy.id).includes(:student_level).each do |student|
  puts "#{student.name} - #{student.student_level.level_name}"
end
```

ActiveRelation queries are also chainable

```
@academy.students_with_levels.where("name ILIKE ?", "Smi%").each do # ...
```

Sort of related a nice article on encapsulation of ActiveRecord queries (methods) - http://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/03/22/respect-the-active-record/

Comment: In my original question: "I know I can do this if I change students from an association to a method, but I don't want to do that as I won't be able to reference students as an association in my other queries."  Perhaps this is the only way to do it though.

Comment: added an 'Additions' section, you are not limited to using the includes techniques from inside activerecord methods